# How can i print the whole sentence without punctuations?

Tags: c

I couldn't print the whole output in a string.

All I know is that %s should work like a loop
for example
printf("%s", str);
works the same as puts(str);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (){
    char str[]="Hello:, student; how are you? This task is easy!";
    char *token;
    char del[] = ", ; : ? !", cp[80];
    int count;
    strcpy(cp, str);
    token = strtok(str, del);
    count = 0;
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, del);
        count++;
        }   
    strtok(str, del);   
    printf("Your sentence has %d words\n", count); 
    puts("The sentence without punctuation charachters is: \n ");
    puts(str); // This should where it show me the output
    return 0 ;
}
```

// I tried to follow the instruction I had to write this code in this form. 
// This is the output that I suppose to get

Hello

student

how

are

you

This

task

is

easy

Your sentence has 11 words
The sentence without punctuation characters is:
Hello student how are you This task is easy

// all I got is ( ignore the extra line between each word)

Hello

student

how

are

you

This

task

is

easy

Your sentence has 11 words
The sentence without punctuation characters is:
Hello

Comment: Perhaps you should store the words somewhere.

Comment: rather than to copy the string unchanged in _cp_ and at the end to print _str_ modified by _strtok_ you just have to concatenate the tokens in _cp_ then to print it, see my answer with a proposal

Answer (score 0):

`strtok(str, del);` modifies its first parameter adding null characters inside, this is why when you print *str* after the calls of *strtok* you got only the first token

you save the string doing `strcpy(cp, str);` but you do not use it, and you also hope 80 is enough ...

A proposal placing the words in *cp* then printing it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
  char str[]="Hello:, student; how are you? This task is easy!";
  char *token;
  char del[] = ", ; : ? !", cp[sizeof(str) + 1];
  int count;
  size_t pos = 0;

  token = strtok(str, del);
  count = 0;
  while( token != NULL )
  {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    strcpy(cp + pos, token);
    pos += strlen(token);
    cp[pos++] = ' ';
    token = strtok(NULL, del);
    count++;
  }
  cp[(pos == 0) ? 0 : (pos - 1)] = 0;
  printf("Your sentence has %d words\n", count); 
  puts("The sentence without punctuation characters is:");
  puts(cp); // This should where it show me the output
  return 0 ;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Hello
student
how
are
you
This
task
is
easy
Your sentence has 9 words
The sentence without punctuation characters is:
Hello student how are you This task is easy
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? I don't know what "   size_t pos = 0; " and "   cp[(pos == 0) ? 0 : (pos - 1)] = 0; " do.